# How can i nest TableRows in TableRowColumn in material ui version 0.20.0 (version is important)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a table in material ui, that has to have two rows in one table row column, it looks like this:

```
<Table>
    <TableHeader>
        ...Some header
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody>
        <TableRow>
            <TableRowColumn>
                <TableRow>            <-------- here is the main issue
                    <TableRowColumn>
                    </TableRowColumn>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableRowColumn>
                    </TableRowColumn>
                </TableRow>
            </TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
    </TableBody>
</Table>
```

To be able to place the second row in table i have to use `TableRow` in `TableRowColumn` but i get a bunch of error due to that:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <td>.
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.
Warning: Unknown event handler property `onHoverExit`. It will be ignored.
Warning: Unknown event handler property `onHover`. It will be ignored.
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `hoverable`.
Warning: React does not recognize the `columnNumber` prop on a DOM element.
```

(different errors in console, not one)

i suppose it is because `TableRowColumn` is the child of `TableRow` and writing them in different order just prevents receiving necessary props.

if that is the case, how can i place two rows in one column specifically for material ui version 0.20.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all i got the issue solved, material ui version 0 does not have the `TableCell` component (availbale only in later versions), which could have solved the issue.
For that specific version to get rid of the errors, the native html tags need to be used:

```
<Table>
    <TableHeader>
        ...Some header
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody>
        <TableRow>
            <TableRowColumn>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
    </TableBody>
</Table>
```

In that case it is possible to fit multiple rows in one row.